# GUI uiwait/uiresume fig Matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface, input, wait

I have a *Matlab GUI* which takes input in `p array` from different functions by different methods, my question is how I can terminates `uiwait` when the input of `p array` is taken, such that when any function of input is terminated successfully. I'm trying to put `uiresume` but it doesn't work on my side.

My code (Main Function):

```
 function varargout = GUI(varargin)
if nargin == 0

    fig = openfig(mfilename,'reuse');
    handles = guihandles(fig);
    guidata(fig, handles);
    uiwait (fig);
    if nargout > 0
        varargout{1} = fig;
    end

elseif ischar(varargin{1}) 

    try
        if (nargout)
            [varargout{1:nargout}] = feval(varargin{:}); 
        else
            feval(varargin{:}); 
        end
    catch
    end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really get what exactly your code is supposed to do.

In any case: 
`uiresume` has to be placed somewhere in a callback of the gui you're opening, since you're above code stops running in the `uiwait`line.

So, you might have an "Ok"-Button on your GUI with a callback à la:

```
function ok_button_callback(object, evt, handles)
    fig = ancestor(object, 'figure');
    uiresume(fig);
end
```